# Displaying message in a GridView Using Layout Grid

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to display a text message in Gridview. The message displays properly but instead of displaying in a single line it comes in different lines

**Expected output**:
My Text Message

**Current output**:
My
Text
Message

Code Snippet :

```
Dim msgRow As New LayoutGrid.Row
msgRow = New LayoutGrid.Row(1)
msgRow.Cells(0).Text = LINE_BREAK_TOKEN
gridOut.Rows.Add(msgRow)

msgRow = New LayoutGrid.Row(1)
msgRow.Cells(0).Text = "My Text Message"
gridOut.Rows.Add(msgRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ColumnSpan property of the Cell, do something like -

```
Dim msgRow As New LayoutGrid.Row
msgRow = New LayoutGrid.Row(1)
msgRow.Cells(0).Text = LINE_BREAK_TOKEN
gridOut.Rows.Add(msgRow)

msgRow = New LayoutGrid.Row(1)
msgRow.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = 6
msgRow.Cells(0).Text = "My Text Message"
gridOut.Rows.Add(msgRow)
```

Assuming you have 6 columns in the table/grid